# How can I skip the first and last element for reading text file no string using double

Tags: arrays, sorting

I got stuck to sum all the item and skip first and last element for Java this is for my next step.

```
  while(sc.hasNext()){
  Arrays.sort(array);
  sum=sc.nextDouble();
  double op=0;
  while(op < 9){
      array[op]= sum;
      op++;
   } 
  }
```

Comment: double op=1; while (op<9-1){...}

Comment: please add the language tag

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you ever need to actually do something special with the first and last elements of the array, and not just dismiss them, here is an easy way to do that.

```
 double op = 0;

  while(op < 9)
  {
      if (op == 0) 
      {/* Preform a special event here */}
      else if (op == 8) 
      {/* Preform a special event here */}
      else
      {
        array[op] = sum;
        op++;
      }
  }
```

I know it's very simple but hey, simple things often work the best ;)